# Run a Script at Game Startup in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, settings

I have a script that runs when the game is loading.
That script sets the resolution, fullscreen, and loads other screen and important settings and applies them.
I have the script attached to a `gameObject` in the main screen that have some game and scene scripts.

The problem is that everytime you return to the main scene, that script runs again causing several bugs.

Is there a way to run a script only at game startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't know a better way than the way you already do: By attaching it to a gameObject in your first scene and putting your setup code in `Start()`.

As possible workarounds for the problems you encounter I would recommend:

- Create an initialization scene which runs even before your main screen. The purpose of that scene is to run any initialization code and then load your main screen scene. You can also use that scene as a loading screen for the game.
- Add a variable `private static bool initialized` to your initialization script. Then wrap the whole code of its Start method into `if (!initialized)` and end that code with `initialized = true`.

Comment: How is the bool helping when reloading the scene, do static variables keep their value between scenes after destroying and loading?

Comment: @Zibelas Yes, static variables keep their value over the lifetime of the whole application. But that's not all that keyword means. See [the official C# documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) for details.

Answer (score 6):

There is the `[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]` attribute. [Excerpting from the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html):

> Allow a runtime class method to be initialized when a game is loaded at runtime without action from the user.
>
> Methods marked `[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]` are invoked after the game has been loaded. This is after the `Awake` method has been invoked.
>
> **Note:** The execution order of methods marked `[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]` is not guaranteed.

```
// Create a non-MonoBehaviour class which displays
// messages when a game is loaded.
using UnityEngine;

class MyClass
{
    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
    static void OnRuntimeMethodLoad()
    {
        Debug.Log("After Scene is loaded and game is running");
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that the method will be called no matter what scene you start up in, and you don't need a specific object in that scene to handle this in `Awake` or `Start`. (And you also don't need to keep track of a flag to skip re-doing that work if play later returns to the same scene)